# Positioning disparity between chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, font-awesome

I searched and wasn't able to find anything related to this. It's a very specific and strange difference between chrome and firefox. If anyone can find the place in the code that's causing it, I would be VERY grateful.

I can't post screenshots, but if you view the jsfiddle in both browsers you'll see what I'm referencing.

Here's my code

http://jsfiddle.net/JSDesign/aJagN/

And a small sample:

```
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="ca-icon"><i class="icon-home"></i></span>
            <div class="ca-content">
                <h2 class="ca-text">Home</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

CSS is on the jsfiddle.

Also, I'm using Font Awesome if that matters.

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was definitely a difference between Chrome/FF. This was occurring because browsers have different default properties. I [**reset**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNJBd.png) the CSS in the example and then tweaked the CSS accordingly, changing the relative positioning and the margins.

Here is an [**updated example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/5bYV6/) that works the same across browsers.

Updated/Modified properties:

```
.ca-menu li a {
    margin-top:14px;
}

.ca-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 36%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the difference beautifully.